# Find the number of integers in the domain of the function $\sqrt{ \frac{3x-x^2}{2-3x} + \sqrt {3-x}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inequality, integers

The required inequality is
$$\sqrt{3-x} (\frac{\sqrt {3-x}.x -3x+2}{3x-2} ) \le 0$$

Obviously $x \le 3$ And $x> \frac 23$ but I am not able to find anything in between. I don’t want to square the inequality because that would break it. How do I proceed ?

Comment: Have you tried substuting different integer values of $x$ in the inequality? You cannot solve for the roots in this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Now, it's enough to solve $$1\geq\frac{x\sqrt{3-x}}{3x-2}$$ for $x\leq3.$

If $$\frac{x}{3x-2}\leq0$$ or
$$0\leq x\leq\frac{2}{3}$$ it's obvious and we got $x=0$ as an integer solution.

But, for $\frac{x}{3x-2}>0$ we obtain:
$$(3x-2)^2\geq x^2(3-x)$$ or
$$x^3+6x^2-12x+4\geq0$$ and we got$$x\in\{-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,2,3\}$$

Comment: There are supposed to be 2 solutions only

Comment: @Aditya I don't agree. For example, for $x=3$ we obtain $0\leq0,$ which is true.

Comment: @Aditya That solution is right. Are you maybe looking for positive integer? In that case we could solve in a simpler way by inspection since $x\le 3$. For the integers those are the solutions.

Comment: @user there is no such restriction

Answer (score 1):

We need

- $3-x \ge 0 \iff x\le 3$
- $2-3x \neq 0 \iff x\neq \frac23$

and for $x\neq 3$

$$\frac{3x-x^2}{2-3x} + \sqrt {3-x}\ge 0\iff \frac{x}{2-3x} \le  \frac1{\sqrt {3-x}}$$

which is always true for $\frac{x}{2-3x}\le 0 \iff \frac23\le x<3$ then for $x <0$ to do not break the inequality we can proceed as follows

$$\frac{x}{2-3x} \le  \frac1{\sqrt {3-x}} \iff \frac{x}{3x-2} \le  \frac1{\sqrt {3-x}}\iff \frac{x^2}{(3x-2)^2} \le  \frac1{3-x}$$

and conclude from here as already indicated.